# Bold doesn't work for a text field...but works for a label

Tags: jasper-reports

When I format a text field to be displayed in "Bold"..it appears as bold in the ireport output, but is not displayed in bold when the same is viewed as a PDF..
any suggestions...?

Answer (score 22):

Just put this in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Really worked for me! Just added this dependency and kept the  isBold="true".

Answer (score 11):

Just had the same problem... I don't know if it will help you, but...

both the text field and the label have a property called "Pdf font name". You have to set this to a bold font (i.e. "Helvetica-Bold" instead of "Helvetica") to render the field bold in a PDF file.

If you edit the JRXML file directly, this setting is contained in the textelement tag after the "size" and "isBold" properties.

Comment: I don't see "Pdf font name" in any of my tags, let alone `textElement>` tag or `font` tag inside of that one. Can you give a specific example of what this would look like? Thx!

Comment: Sadly PDF-Font-Name is now deprecated!

Answer (score 4):

PdfFont name is obsolete. Use font extension instead. Add jasperreports-fonts-xxx.jar into the classpath. Or try http://sites.google.com/site/xmedeko/code/misc/jasperreports-pdf-font-mapping

Answer (score 1):

An excellent article on here gives the answer...

javaskeleton.blogspot.co.at/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html

So you have to add the TrueType file of the font you want from C:\Windows\Fonts into iReport. In the latest version of iReport, which is 4.01, you go to Tools -> Options -> iReport Tab -> Fonts tab -> Install Font.

In Windows 7, the fonts aren't visible inside the File Explorer as opened by any other program. So, you'll need to copy the Fonts you want (whose normal, 'bold', 'italic' and 'bold italic' ttf files are clogged as one by Windows in the C:\Windows\Fonts folder under the typeface heading e.g. Verdana) into some other folder.

Now choose the file containing the 'normal' version of the typeface (the file named same as the typeface name), under 'Install Font' in iReport. Follow the wizard, add the other typeface versions and finish it.

After that, you need to make a jar extension and store it in a folder which preferable does not require Adminstrator permissions to perform an edit. You can't save it in the default folder shown unless you've opened iReport under Administrator permissions.

After saving it, manually transfer it to the default folder shown earlier, which is the place for storage of extensions to iReport, (Installation folder)\ireport\modules\ext\ (yourfontfile.jar).

After this process, open the iReport tab under Tools -> Options again in iReport, add the jar file to the classpath.

And you're done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I solved it by changing the version of jar file of Jasper in my web application.I compiled my jrxml file in Jaspersoft iReport 5.6.0 and the version of jar file of Jasper is also 5.6.0.
Previously it was 5.5.0 that is why it was not appearing in bold through the web application.